# how to spot weekly versus monthly prices in an area

Tags: distributions, standard-deviation

I have price rents for properties distributed over the country for the last 2 years (a total amount of 2M properties). The problem is that some of the prices are monthly and other weekly.

To spot the weekly prices I am trying to calculate the standard deviation based on areas they belong to. However some of the distribution are skewed (which suggests maybe the usage of skewness/kurtosis).

However I am not sure how to implement a "strategy" to solve this problem.
Any idea?

Comment: Do you have other covariables? which? Do you know for at least some properties if weekly/monthly?

Comment: How is the data currently stored?